# c#winforms упаковка в .exe с данными SQLite

Tags: c#, winforms

уважаемые программисты, помогите пожалуйста, пытаюсь собирать .exe файл телефонный справочник с БД SQLite, без ошибок Ребилдится, после устанавливаю приложению, пытаюсь запустит приложение просто не запускается окно , пару раз крутится стрелка и все больше никаких действий не происходит , пробовал просто без Баз данных все прекрасно работает.  проблема возникает с SQLite и базой. как исправить помогите пожалуйста !

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выложил код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;


namespace prob
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("telefon");
        private SQLiteCommand sql_cmd;
        private SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data source=telefon.db");
        SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
        int id;

        public void Connect()
        {
            con.Open();
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select * From telefon", con);
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }

        private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
        {
            Connect();
            con.Open();
            sql_cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            sql_cmd.CommandText = txtQuery;
            sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        private DataTable AutoNumberedTable(DataTable SourceTable)

        {
            DataTable ResultTable = new DataTable();
            DataColumn AutoNumberColumn = new DataColumn();
            AutoNumberColumn.ColumnName = "id";
            AutoNumberColumn.DataType = typeof(int);
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            AutoNumberColumn.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
            ResultTable.Columns.Add(AutoNumberColumn);
            ResultTable.Merge(SourceTable);
            return ResultTable;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Connect();
            dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lime;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 13, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 25;
            dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Times new Roman", 12);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 40;
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 178;
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 120;
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width = 116;
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 80;

            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "ID";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderCell.Value = "Name";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "work number";
            dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Value = "cell number";
            dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "depertament";
            dataGridView1.Columns[5].HeaderCell.Value = "Faks";
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        }

        private void Addbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "insert into telefon(id, name, depertament, worknumber, phone, faks) Values (null, '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "',  '" + textBox5.Text + "', '" + textBox6.Text + "')";
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = AutoNumberedTable(dt);
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Adedd");

            textBox2.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox3.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox4.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox5.Text = string.Empty;
            textBox6.Text = string.Empty;
            Connect();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            textBox2.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            textBox4.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            textBox5.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            textBox6.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }

        private void delete(int id)
        {
            string sql = "DELETE FROM telefon WHERE id=" + id + "";
            sql_cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con);

            //OPEN CON, EXECUTE DELETE, CLOSE CON

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql_cmd);
                adapter.DeleteCommand = con.CreateCommand();
                adapter.DeleteCommand.CommandText = sql;

                // PROMT FOR CONFIRMATION

                if (sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Deleted");
                }

                con.Close();

                Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Deletebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selected = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(selected);
            delete(id);
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
           
            string query = "Select * From telefon where name like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR depertament like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR worknumber like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' OR phone like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            DataSet dset = new DataSet();
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con);
            SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Fill(dset);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
        }

        private void Updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                sql_cmd = new SQLiteCommand("update telefon SET name='" + textBox1.Text + "', depertament='" + textBox1.Text + "', worknumber='" + textBox1.Text + "', phone='" + textBox1.Text + "', faks='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
                sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
                con.Close();
                Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка новичка - вера в магию и телепатию. Нет здесь никакой магии, есть только ошибки в коде, который вы не покажете или при сборке неизвесно какого инсталятора, но вы не скажете, как собираете, а может и при установке файлы не туда кладутся, но к сожалению отсюда я плохо вижу содержимое вашего диска.

Comment: исправил , код добавил, изображение с процессом Ребилдин тоже добавил . может дадите напутствие какие могут быть проблемы,  надо ли добавлять файл с базой данных в Application folder ? решение собирал по видеоурокам FoxLearn.

Comment: Ну вот, совсем другое дело